# Consuming WebService PDF in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services

I have a database where via a webservice I want to consume the data in a project in xcode. The xml webservice that gives me is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Document>
        <idTypeDocument>80</idTypeDocument>
        <idProject>0</idProject>
        <document>JVBERi0xLjQNCiXT9MzhDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PCA...</document>
        <contentType>application/pdf</contentType>
    </Document>
</Document>
```

As I can put in xcode for reading `<document>` can transform and display the pdf? In advance thank you very much!